# Returns Data Issue in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to know about the below shown Issue :

JS Code:

```
 Template.main.helpers({
        ItemName: function() {
            var self = this;
           console.log("helpers : " +self.fieldoptions);
            return _.map(self.fieldoptions,function(p) 
               {
                  p.parent = self;
                 return p;
              });
        }
    });
```

HTML Code :

```
 {{#each ItemName}}

        {{this.parent.fname}}                      

   {{/each}}
```

The above Js return code doesn't show the html.So how to show the above return code in HTML.I didn't get any idea about this.So please help me?

Comment: where is `fieldoptions` defined and how?

Comment: fieldoption is the collection field name.@ Christian Fritz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear to me so I'll write what I think is happening. You should have at least 2 files on your meteor directory (the one created with `meteor create`)

`template.main.html` that if you are not using any router to make the template append to the body should look like

```
<head>
   <title>My title</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> templateMain}}
</body>

<template name="templateMain">
    {{#each ItemName}}
        {{fname}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

`template.main.js` with something around these lines

```
FieldNames = new Meteor.Collection('fieldname');

if( Meteor.isServer && FieldNames.find().count() === 0)
  _.each(['one','two','three','four'], function(value, index){ 
      FieldNames.insert({ fname : value, index : index });        
  });

if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.main.helpers({
      ItemName: function() {

          return FieldNames.find();
      }
  });
}
```

So what I think was happening was that you didn't include the template on the body.

Let me know if something is not clear.